# API to get all zip codes in: Counties, States, and Legislative Districts

Tags: gis, zipcode

I have a preliminary requirement for the following:

I need to get all the zip codes in a given:

- State
- County
- Congressional District

(Note: USA-only.)

More explicitly:

- Given a list of states, when I select a state, then I get all the zip codes in the state.
- Given a list of counties, when I select a county, then I get all the zip codes in the county.
- Given a list of congressional districts, when I select a district, then I get all the zip codes in the district.

So I need a way to get listings of those areas and then I need a way to retrieve zip codes for a given area. This seems to be a somewhat uncommon direction to go (retrieving zips for areas, versus the reverse).

Are there APIs available for this or will I have to create my own GIS DB and perform intersections on zip/areas polygons? If the latter, what APIs are available to populate a custom solution with?

Comment: I may be able to start with a full list of zip codes and query state, county, and congressional district APIs individually, populating a relational DB along the way (wouldn't need to be geospatial database). We'll see what kind of solutions SO yields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like https://www.zipinfo.com/ has everything you are looking for.